# Android image added programatically from file not sizing properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-image, android-resources, android-drawable

I have an Android app which displays a collection of data in an ExpandableListView. The expandable list view has only one child. In that child I am adding several TextView elements, and after the last one an ImageView.

That ImageView is the problem.

If I set the image resource from the drawable folder using

```
R.drawable.test_image
```

it shows like this:

[image: Image added from Resource]

But if I add the image programmatically, like this:

```
ImageView drinkImage = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.drink_image, null, false);
// FileString is "/storage/sdcard0/.WhatToDrink/drinkImages/1388450237870.jpg" 
Drawable drinkImageDrawable = Drawable.createFromPath(fileString);

drinkImage.setImageDrawable(drinkImageDrawable);
```

It shows like this:

[image: Added from file]

Identical file. I grabbed the file itself from the storage and moved it to my drawable folder and adding it that way works perfectly.

ImageView xml code:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentDescription="Drink Image"
    android:id="@+id/drink_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

ExpandableListView XML Code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.bluelimecrew.whattodrink.DrinkListActivity.DrinkListFragment">
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/listContainer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/drinkList"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </ExpandableListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/backToDashboard"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/nextButtons"
            android:text="@string/backToDashboard" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas?

I'm running this on a Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Drawable.createFromPath](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java#Drawable.createFromPath%28java.lang.String%29) will not have the context information thus cannot scale the bitmap properly (because it does not know screen density etc).

As you can see in the source code, it will call `drawableFromBitmap(null, bm, null, null, pathName)`. The first parameter (`null`) is the resources reference.

Instead, use a constructor that receives the `Context` or `Resources` so that it can scale it bitmap properly.

Check [new BitmapDrawable(Resources res, String path)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.java#BitmapDrawable.%3Cinit%3E%28android.content.res.Resources%2Candroid.graphics.Bitmap%29)

You can see that the BitmapDrawable constructors which do not receive the resources are [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html).

Comment: Do you mean use BitmapDrawable? A different constructor? I'm confused.

Comment: since you know it is a Bitmap, yes I suggest using a BitmapDrawable _directly_ so that you can pass the Resources. 
If you check the source code of Drawable class, you'll see that `Drawable.createFromPath` loads the Bitmap and calls [drawableFromBitmap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.java#Drawable.drawableFromBitmap%28android.content.res.Resources%2Candroid.graphics.Bitmap%2Cbyte%5B%5D%2Candroid.graphics.Rect%2Candroid.graphics.Rect%2Cjava.lang.String%29) which also creates a BitmapDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

not sure, because images can be tricky, but try this

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:contentDescription="Drink Image"
    android:id="@+id/drink_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: I've already tried all the different layout_width and layout_height options.

Comment: That is the whole XML layout. I'm inflating that and adding that to an ExpandableListView. Edited my question to have ExpandableListView.